# Android Studio - Could not determine Gradle JDK (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I initially installed the android studio application, but when I open the android studio file from another device I can't open it on my Android studio. The problem is in the "Could not determine Gradle JDK" section. I'm still new to using Android Stdio. I have tried reinstalling the Android Studio app, but the result is back to the original problem.
thank you for helping
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztc5z.png)

Answer (score 0):

An android project keeps the path to Java Development Kit - JDK. If you open the project on another device, this paths often won't math. Android Studio is offering to solve this error easily - just click "Use Embedded JDK" hint.